# Future in scala cann't run asynchronously when the future number larger than cpu core number

Tags: multithreading, scala, future, blocking

I used Future to implement a multi-thread function in scala language. But when the future number lager than cpu core number, the threads were splited to groups. And the threads in one group completed, then the other threads in other groups started. My code and output were listed below. Is there something wrong in my code, and how to fix it?

---

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object FutrueTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val threads=10
        def ft(): Future[String] = Future {
            for (i <- 1 until 3) {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                println(Thread.currentThread().getName + "\t" + i)
            }

            Thread.currentThread().getName + " end..."
        }

        var fs = Set[Future[String]]()
        for (j <- 1 until threads) {
            val f = ft
            f.onComplete {
                case _ => "Thread :" + j + " complete"
            }
            fs += f
        }

        fs.foreach(f => {
            Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf)
        })
    }
}
```

### output in terminal

> ```
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13  1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15  1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11  1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1   1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3   1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7   1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9   1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5   1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1   2
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15  2
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9   2
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3   2
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11  2
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13  2
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7   2
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5   2
>
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15  1
> ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15  2
> ```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. If you want to change it you need to use a respective execution context which fits your requirements.

Comment: You didn't specify what the desired behavior is so how can we say "_How to fix it?_" What is particularly interesting is what you want  if `threads` were set to something big like`10000`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own execution context.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object CustomExecutionContext {
  private val availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()

  implicit val nDExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(availableProcessors * N)) // N is number of threads
}
```

**Another solution**: Control the number of future execution in parallel using `FixedThreadPool`. It will start 10 futures first and then start others after completing these.

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
```

**Third solution**: You can use throttle execution context. [Refer](https://gist.github.com/kevinwright/4949162)

Use this instead of global execution context.

```
implicit val ec = ThrottledExecutionContext(maxConcurrents = 4)(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global)
```

It will limit the parallelism.

**4th solution**: You can use `akka fsm` to throttle.